# Empty reponse body Http Angular 2 with status 200

Tags: json, angular, typescript, http

I'm working with Angular2 for front-end developpement and Scala play framework for back-end.
My problem is that the back-end send the Json I need, tested with Postman it works, but it seems that angular doesn't receive anything in body.

Client.ts

```
public static getAllUncompleteCompanyForm(http: Http, userId: string, headers: Headers, apiUrl: string): Observable<Response> {
            return http.get(apiUrl + Client.version + 'scoring/uncomplete-form/companies/' + userId, {headers: headers});
        }`
```

CompanyFormService.ts

```
getAllUncompleteCompanyForm(userId: string) {
        let headers = getHeader(this.token());
        return Client.getAllUncompleteCompanyForm(this.http, userId, headers, environment.backendUrl).subscribe(response => {
            console.log(response);
        },
            error => console.log(error));
    }
```

Here's the log : 
[image]

What am I doing wrong ?

**EDIT**

When I use `response.json()` I get this :

```
Unexpected end of JSON input
```

**EDIT 2**

Content type of response header is text/plain. Maybe that's a lead for something ? However when I send application/json the result is the same there's nothing in the body

Comment: try response.json() to parse response

Comment: which version of angular you're using?

Comment: @KAMRULHASANSHAHED Angular 2 as mentionned

Comment: @FatehMohamed Look at the edit

Comment: @AluanHaddad .  The server code is fine it returns what i expect and Postman show me exactly what I need

Comment: OK. I noticed that your service method is very silly. You're returning the subscription... why? Also your error handler should be removed. That's no way to handle errors. It's just a way to write more code. Too much code... everywhere... stop...

Comment: @AluanHaddad It's just typing, there's no difference If I remove it and anyway I subscribe to it

Comment: But your component can't do anything and it has nothing to do with typing. You can't do anything with the service response because you're not returning it

Comment: When I use the method from the CompanyFormService and log it , even if i return it there"s nothing but the response

Comment: You have to use response._body to access the body but its showing empty in your response itself...